# Setting vim option, what is the trailing less-than for?

Tags: vim

[This page](https://vim-jp.org/vim-users-jp/2010/03/21/Hack-133.html) has `setl bin< eol<` in the script. vim help doesn't have documentation that I can find on what the trailing less-than does, and testing appears to indicate that it's ignored.

What is the purpose of the trailing less-than on the option names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `:help setl` gave me this:

> :setl[ocal] {option}< Set the local value of {option} to its global value by
>             copying the value.
>             {not in Vi}

Comment: _augh_ Thanks, I didn't realise there was separate help for setlocal. (I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me.)